# How can I run a continuous background job with Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

I have been using Sidekiq successfully to run background jobs that are initiated by user actions in a Rails 3.2 application. My particular application involves sending and receiving data from and external source via a third party API.

I need to keep data synchronized with this external source by continuously checking for each user if there is data available to be downloaded.

All of my background jobs thus far are user-initiated as I mentioned above. My question is, if I want to continuously check for the existence of external data for each user, in a `while` loop I imagine:

```
# pseudocode
while true

  for user in User.active
    data = user.get_data
    next if data.blank?

    UserDataWorker.perform_async(user.id)

  end
end
```

then where do I put the code above? I get confused on how to spawn a continuous task. I don't want to put the code in a Sidekiq worker, because it will just be a job that never completes. Or should I do that?

I don't want to put it in a rake task, because then how do I monitor that rake task? Everything I've read about Sidekiq seems to point to a Worker running a task that is finite and is able to be completed or errored out. I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: how about using cron job ?

Comment: I thought about that, but cron is more task-oriented and what I'm looking for is more like a daemon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby multithreading is just for that. Spawn a thread in your initializers folder:

```
Thread.new do

  loop do

    for user in User.active
      data = user.get_data
      next if data.blank?

      UserDataWorker.perform_async(user.id)
    end

    sleep 1

  end
end
```

If your checks don't need much resources, should be allright.

Comment: The problem with this is when rails crashes or its been stopped then this script will also stop running as it's running on the same process. Is there a way to run this in a separate process? @AKWF

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a gem like sidekiq scheduler: https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler.

You could start the work every minute or couple seconds easily. It would be running in the sidekiq process itself, which should work for you, since you need sidekiq running all the time.